# What is the use of Sencha Cmd?

Tags: maven, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

Recently, i came across about Sencha Cmd.

http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

It looks like similar to Maven.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **CLI** provide functionality for creating `sencha touch` and `extjs` projects, Also it will help you integrate [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) platform to sencha project to build it for various native platforms. It also has lot of feature like creating controllers and views also it build the project in `minified` source to reduce the app size.